# If $(u_n)_n,(v_n)_n$ are seq. in a Hilbert space and $(e_k)_k$ is an ONB, then $\sum_k|\sum_n(u_n,e_k)(v_n,e_k)|≤\sum_n\sum_k|(u_n,e_k)(v_n,e_k)|$

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Let

- $(H,\langle\;\cdot\;,\;\cdot\;\rangle)$ be a Hilbert space and $\left\|\;\cdot\;\right\|$ be the norm induced by $\langle\;\cdot\;,\;\cdot\;\rangle$
- $(u_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}\subseteq H$ and $(v_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}\subseteq H$ with $$\sum_{n\in\mathbb N}\left\|u_n\right\|\left\|v_n\right\|<\infty\tag 1$$
- $(e_k)_{k\in\mathbb N}$ be an orthonormal basis of $H$

> I want to prove, that $$\sum_{k\in\mathbb N}\left|\sum_{n\in\mathbb N}\langle u_n,e_k\rangle\langle v_n,e_k\rangle\right|\le\sum_{n\in\mathbb N}\sum_{k\in\mathbb N}\left|\langle u_n,e_k\rangle\langle v_n,e_k\rangle\right|\tag 2\;.$$

(I've found $(2)$ in the proof of a theorem and don't understand why it holds)

Comment: It is only the triangle inequality applied to the sum on the index $n$. The assumptions assure that the infinite sums are absolutely convergent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a series $\sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}} a_n$ converges then
$$
 \left| \sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}}^n a_n \right|
 \leq \sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}} |a_n|
$$
(where the right hand side might be infinite). Now
$$
 \sum_{k \in \mathbb{N}}
 \left|
 \sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\langle u_n, e_k \rangle \langle v_n, e_k \rangle
 \right|
\leq
 \sum_{k \in \mathbb{N}}
 \sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}}
 |\langle u_n, e_k \rangle \langle v_n, e_k \rangle|
=
 \sum_{n \in \mathbb N}
 \sum_{k\in\mathbb N}|\langle u_n,e_k\rangle\langle v_n,e_k\rangle|.
$$
For the equality in the second step we used that all summands are non-negative, and thus can be rearranged however we want.